# How to soft delete a record in table A, with all of its references in 3 other tables

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, soft-delete

I have e a problem where I have a table 'A' with primary key as id, and this id is being used as a foreign key in table B, C, and D which are having huge data.

Now i want to soft delete this id from table A.

So my requirement is , when i soft delete this id from table A, it should be deleted from all the referenced table i.e B, C and D.

**Note** : There is no hard delete using hibernate, I have to delete it softly, that means making this field as **isActive = false** in db

Comment: You can it do it by making null reference in the foreign key in B,C,D table. And then delete it.

Comment: But B,C,D table are having huge records , if i make it null it will impact performance.

Comment: then make a thread call for deleting this tables.